# Confused about Linked Duplicates

Tags: instances

Could someone enlighten me as to the difference between 'Relations>Make Single User' and 'Apply>Make Instances Real'?

I think I'm super confused!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linked duplicates are two Objects which share the same data.

[image]

If you add an empty and then go to the object data properties tab under instancing, you can add collection to instance on the empty object.

[image]

Which you would typically add from *Add > Collection Instance*

[image]

Make Instances Real turns those empty instances into the actual objects that make up the collection it is an instance of.